# Array not getting cleared to null or empty in setState on click in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

Array not getting cleared to null or empty in setState on click in react.

When I click on the submit button, the array must be set to []. It is setting to [], but on change the previous array of items comes into the array.

```
let questions = [];
let qns = [];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
      btnDisabled: true,
      //questions: [],
    };    
  }

  changeRadioHandler = (event, j) => {
    this.setState({ checked: true });
    const qn = event.target.name;
    const id = event.target.value;
    let idVal = this.props.dat.mat.opts;
    let text = this.props.dat.mat.opt;
    let userAnswer = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
      userAnswer.push(false);
    }
    const option = text.map((t, index) => ({
      text: t.text,
      userAnswer: userAnswer[index],
    }));
    const elIndex = option.findIndex((element) => element.text === id);
    const options = { ...option };
    options[elIndex] = {
      ...options[elIndex],
      userAnswer: true,
    };
    const question = {
      options,
      id: event.target.value,
      qn,
    };   
    questions[j] = options;
    qns = questions.filter((e) => {
      return e != null;
    });    
    console.log(qns, qns.length);
    this.setState({ qns });
    if (qns.length === idVal.length) {
      this.setState({
        btnDisabled: false,
      });
    }
  };

  submitHandler = () => {    
    console.log(this.state.qns, this.state.questions);    
    this.setState({ qns: [] }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.qns, this.state.questions)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="matrix-bd">        
        {this.props.dat.mat && (
          <div class="grid">
            {this.props.dat.mat.opts.map((questions, j) => {
              return (
                <div class="rows" key={j}>
                  <div class="cell main">{questions.text}</div>
                  {this.props.dat.mat.opt.map((element, i) => {
                    return (
                      <div class="cell" key={i}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          id={j + i}
                          name={questions.text}
                          value={element.text}
                          onChange={(event) =>
                            this.changeRadioHandler(event, j)
                          }
                        ></input>
                        <label htmlFor={j + i}>{element.text}</label>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          <button
            type="button"           
            class="btn btn-primary"
            disabled={this.state.btnDisabled}
            onClick={this.submitHandler}
          >
            SUBMIT
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

On button click submit, the array must be set to [] and when on change, the value must be set to the emptied array with respect to its index.

Comment: you mean `this.setState({ qns: [] }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.qns, this.state.questions)
    );` in the console the value of `this.state.qns` is not empty?

Comment: The value of this.state.qns (on click submit) becomes empty, but when I perform on change operation after clicking on the submit button, the previous array value comes in place. Like, the selected value gets inserted into the array with respect to index by replacing the old value.

Comment: Probably because you're using global mutable arrays `questions` & `qns`. Please double check the data flow, and in case you're still stuck, share a [pen](https://codepen.io/) with the issue reproducable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found out the solution.

After adding componentDidMount and setting questions variable to null solved my issue.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    questions = [];
  };
```

Thanks all for your efforts and responses!

Answer (score 0):

```
changeRadioHandler = (event, j) => {
 // the better way is use local variable
 let questions = [];
 let qns = [];
 ...

}


submitHandler = () => {    
 console.log(this.state.qns, this.state.questions);  
 this.setState({ qns: [] }, () =>
  console.log(this.state.qns, this.state.questions)
  )}
 // clear the previous `qns`
 // if u use local variable. you don't need those lines
 // this.qns = []
 // this.questions = []
}
```

Comment: The issue still persists after adding the last line to the submit function.

Comment: @skp I update my answer. if it's not work. share a pen with the issue reproducable